# Unable to encrypt connectionStrings using ExeCommand in Wix project

Tags: c#, rsa, custom-action, wix3.5

Clients need encryption their SQL credential in web.Config and we delivered web application using WIX installer.

In command mode we can encrypt connection strings as Administrator mode

```
ASPNET_REGIIS -PEF "connectionStrings" "C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\ProdectType\WebApplicationName"
```

Recently I had done some code in wixproject

```
<!--Find Framework Path-->

<Property Id="FRAMEWORKBASEPATH">
  <RegistrySearch Id="FindFrameworkDir" Root="HKLM"  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework"  Name="InstallRoot" Type="raw" >
  </RegistrySearch>
</Property>

<!--Search aspnet_regiis.exe-->

<Property Id="ASPNETREGIIS" >
  <DirectorySearch Path="[FRAMEWORKBASEPATH]" Depth="4" Id="FindAspNetRegIis">
    <FileSearch Name="aspnet_regiis.exe" MinVersion="2.0.5" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<!--Web.config  : "C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\ProdectType\WebApplicationName\Web.config"
<!--INSTALLDIR  : "C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\ProdectType\WebApplicationName"-->
<!--Now set custom action for command-->
<CustomAction Directory="INSTALLDIR" Execute="deferred" Id="EncryptWebConfig" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="[ASPNETREGIIS]  -PEF  'connectionStrings'  'C:\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\ProdectType\WebApplicationName' " Return="check"></CustomAction>

<!--Execute-->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="EncryptWebConfig" After="InstallFiles" ></Custom>      
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<!--Admin Privileged-->
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
```

While installing, its showing command window but connection string is not encrypted and also check log files but still I can not find any error

Comment: Have you tried this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs

Comment: let me work on it @Workaholic

Comment: its not working

Comment: Is it an issue with the spelling in your code? ProdectType != ProductType

Comment: @DavidDaugherty that is unnecessary because it's hand written mistake